# I installed TeX and LaTeX in Windows. When I try to start it, Windows asks what app I want to use. There's no app for TeX

Tags: editors, ide

I have tried Google Play Store and I have looked in all program folders in Windows system files.

Comment: what are you trying to start?? And how?

Comment: `.tex` files are just text files you can open them in any editor you wish. notepad for example. But you may have a tex-specific editor that can help with the syntax and running of commands. If you mean you want to click on a tex file and something opens, just pick any editor you like.

Comment: The way too long list of tex-specific editors is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/107497 or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the question refers to right-click or double-click on a *.tex file. Although is is possible to configure Windows that way, a new user should start at the basic level, with the TeXworks program.

TeXworks (for Windows) comes with TeXlive and MiKTeX. It is a GUI program with built-in PDF viewer for the result. If your installation did not install TeXWorks, then open the TeX installer and install TeXworks. I believe you can also install it by other means.

Launch TeXworks, then open your *.tex file from there. You can edit it, and compile it.

If all you want to do is edit a *tex file, it is plain utf-8 text. Your best bet is a program such as Notepad++ (not Windows Notepad). Be sure to use utf-8 encoding, without BOM (no byte order mark).

There are other TeX GUI programs that offer math symbol support. See the above comments.